# Multiform data send to server using iPhone sdk

Tags: xcode, http, post, nsdata, nsmutableurlrequest

I’ve been trying to follow some examples for uploading data to a website.  I want to save the message as a .txt file.  Any ideas what to do here?

```
- (IBAction)sendSerializedGreeting:(id)sender;
{
    NSString *message;
    message =@"Here we go for a test message.";
    // Show a loading indicator
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    NSString *greetingURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.site.com/upload.php"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:greetingURL]
             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];  

    NSDictionary *headerFieldsDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8", @"Content-Type", nil];

    [theRequest setHTTPBody:[message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [theRequest setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headerFieldsDict];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    // create the connection with the request and start loading the data
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if (theConnection == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create the connection");
    }
}
```

Here is the upload.php file.  I’m assuming the issue is with this but not sure.  I don’t know where the filename gets set in the example above.  This code was used from somewhere else.

```
<?php
$uploaddir = './';      //Uploading to same directory as PHP file

$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

$uploadFile = $file;
$randomNumber = rand(0, 99999); 
$newName = $uploadDir . $randomNumber . $uploadFile;

if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "Temp file uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Temp file not uploaded.";
}

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $newName)) {

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sending a image to server through this code .... use for your text file or any type of multiform data

```
     NSString *strUrl=@"http://www.site.com/upload.php";
        NSLog(@"%@",strUrl);
        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest  requestWithURL:url
                                                                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                            timeoutInterval:130.0];

        // file name of user picture
// I am sending a image to server
        NSString *fileName=[[eMailTxtField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"@" withString:@"-"]  stringByAppendingString:@".jpg"];
        //image data
        UIImage *userImage=imgUser.image;
        NSData *imageData =UIImageJPEGRepresentation(userImage, 90);

        NSMutableData *myRequestData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
        [myRequestData appendData:[NSData dataWithBytes:[postData UTF8String] length:[postData length]]];


        NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"--"];
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
        [myRequestData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [myRequestData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", fileName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [myRequestData appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [myRequestData appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
        [myRequestData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [ request setHTTPMethod: @"POST" ];

        [ request setHTTPBody: myRequestData ];
        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSError *error;
        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
        if (!error && returnData) {
            NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[returnData bytes]];
            [self registerWithJsonString:content];
        }
        else{
            [self showServerNotFoundError];
        }
```

Comment: `$_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name']`  is for receiving this.

Comment: `uploadfile` is the field name mentioned in the above code. dont panic with boundary. it is just for separation

Comment: Can you clarify this line: [myRequestData appendData:[NSData dataWithBytes:[postData UTF8String] length:[postData length]]]; - what is the "postData" object?